# How to implement Drag and Drop in Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to make a drag and drop in my Android App.
This exemple ([Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html)) needs a Long Click to start the `Drag`
But I want a `Drag and Drop` **inside** my App just like Facebook Messenger:
[image]

I also want that when the icon is clicked, a pop-up to be open
is there a way to use it inside an app?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully think this may solve everything but this might be worth a shot.
Try adding a frame layout as the parent(top level) layout of all of your activities' layout. Then add the chathead view on this frame layout which has the same child level as your activities' layout. This way you can still use the chathead while still interacting with your activity. @vinijow's answer is very helpful with this topic.